# Compare 2 Excel tables with 4 columns each using formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my first post and i hope i did everything right and the screenshot is shown. Unfortunately i don't know how to attach files yet.

Now my problem:

I have to compare 2 Excel-Tables with 1200 rows. I'm looking for a solution with formulas not with vba.

The tables have a different number of rows and different entries. How can I find all the differences and set a marker for example in "Diff col4". Does anyone has a tip or solution for me?

[image]

My formula in column "Ok"

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$15:$B$20,$B5,$C$15:$C$20,$C5,$D$15:$D$20,$D5,$E$15:$E$20,$E5)>0,"X","")
```

My formula in column "not in table2"

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$15:$B$20,$B5,$C$15:$C$20,$C5,$D$15:$D$20,$D5,$E$15:$E$20,$E5)=0,"X","")
```

Comment: Have you tried using a vlookup (or better match and index) between the tables?  Is column1 the "key" field?  Doing a match/index from table1 to table2 for each column, then set OK to "x" if all four fields match?

Comment: You need to define a unique key for the data (could be a combination of columns) in order to determine the difference. Otherwise, the result is indeterminate for cases that there's a row in Table 1 with values A,B,C,D in 4 columns, while there are two rows in Table 2 with values  A,B,E,F and G,H,C,D.   Once the key is determined, use `match([key], [Table 2], 0)` to determine the row and compare the values of each column (located by `index()`, `offset()`, etc.).  If the unique key is a combined-value, you may need a helper column.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. My solution may not be optimal but it seems to work. Now table1 has the columns B,C,D,E and table2 M,N,O,P. You are right, i will have to build a unique key from 2 columns. To keep the example simple i used just column B. 

For example search '16809317' from column B (table1) in column M (table2). If the entry is found compare column O (col3 in table2) with column D (col3 in table1).

'=IF(NOT(ISERROR(INDEX($M$5:$P$11,MATCH($B9,$M$5:$M$11,0),1))),IF(INDIRECT("O"&(MATCH($B9,$M$5:$M$11,0)+4))=D9,"ok","not equal"),"not found")